# Error Select WebSQL

Tags: html, select, undefined, web-sql

Im having a problem trying to get a select from my local websql database.

I have a table named "clientes". Here's my code:

```
var db = openDatabase("test", "", "", 1024*1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM clientes', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                 
            console.log(results.rows.item(i));
        }
    });         
})
```

I got the rows

```
{
    "ClienteCiudad": "MADRID",
    "ClienteFechaDesde": 2013,
    "ClienteLegalDenominacion": null,
    "ClienteLegalNrTributario": null
}
```

But when I try to filter with a WHERE I got undefined

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE ClienteCiudad="Madrid"', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                 
            console.log(results.rows.item(i));
        }
    });         
})
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
      var searchfor = "Madrid";
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE ClienteCiudad=?', [searchfor], function (tx, results) {
         var len = results.rows.length;
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                 
             console.log(results.rows.item(i));
          }
       });         
})
```